# AngularJS Module is undefined while creating service using Factory method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am learning AngularJS in MVC and created service to pass my model to Angular Controller. But It gives me error

> JavaScript runtime error: 'accountModule' is undefined

This is what I am doing:

**AccountController.cs**

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var accounts = new List<Accounts>
                        {
                            new Accounts
                                {
                                    Id = 111,
                                    Designation = "Tech Lead",
                                    Name = "AAA"
                                },
                            new Accounts
                                {
                                    Id = 222,
                                    Designation = "Softwre Engineer",
                                    Name = "BBB"
                                },
                            new Accounts
                                {
                                    Id = 111,
                                    Designation = "Project Manager",
                                    Name = "CCC"
                                }
                        };

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        };

    var accountJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts, Formatting.None, settings);

    return this.View("Index", (object)accountJson);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Modules/Account/Account.js"></script>
<div ng-app="accountModule">
    <div ng-controller="accountController">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        <div class="container" ng-init="employees in {{employees}}">
            <h2>Employee Details</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Designation
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                        <td>
                            {{emp.id}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{emp.name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{emp.designation}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @*{{emps}}*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    accountModule.factory('accountService', function() {
            var factory = {};

            factory.employees = @Html.Raw(Model);

            return factory;
        });

</script>
```

**Account.js**

```
var account = angular.module('accountModule',[]);

account.controller('accountController', [
    '$scope', 'accountService', function ($scope, accountService) {


        $scope.employees = accountService.employees;

        $scope.message = "Hi on " + (new Date()).toDateString();
    }
]);
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the inline script right after the account.js.

Also the variable should be `account` instead of `accountModule`

**Code**

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="account.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//account.factory('accountService', function() { //this is alternative use below one
angular.module('accountModule').factory('accountService', function() {
    var factory = {};

    factory.employees = @Html.Raw(Model);

    return factory;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your last line `Also the variable should be account instead of accountModule` solved my problem. Thanks for the help. Now I am able to pass Model to AngularJS controller. :)

Comment: Also I would like to mention that moving service to JS will not work as I have to pass data from `cshtml` to controller.

Answer (score 0):

MVC View rendering order- 
1. Starts with the *View* first and then related bundles(external CSS,JS).

2.In order to pass the Model data we need to have a inline element in .cshtml file(though not recommended) but, if this is the way to go then, use service injection to related controller-

```
@section scripts
    {
    <script>
    (function (undefined) {
        window.app.factory('searchBinding', function () {
            return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
        })
    })(undefined);

</script>
}
```

3. Now, as the above code is inline it gets executed with the *View* itself, but Angular module is not yet defined as its yet to be downloaded. Hence it will throw the *undefined* error.
4. In order to resolve this we can use *RenderSection* in _Layout.cshtml after all the core files(bundles) are loaded , this forces even the inline sections to load only after these files are loaded(in step-2. @section scripts was used for this purpose).Snippet from _Layout.cshtml file

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs");
   @RenderSection("scripts",false);